# Shifting with floats

Tags: floating-point, bit-manipulation, precision, bitwise-operators, byte-shifting

```
float a = 1.0 + ((float) (1 << 25))
float b = 1.0 + ((float) (1 << 26))
float c = 1.0 + ((float) (1 << 27))
```

What are the float values of a, b, and c after running this code? Explain why the bit layout of a, b, and c causes each value to be what it is.

Comment: That sounds like a good question, for homework. The first part of the question is easy enough to answer by running the code so I suggest you start with that, then think about how to explain the results.

Comment: The title of this question is a strong sign you do not understand what you're doing. This does not shift `float`s, it shifts `int`s.

Comment: @EOF: Nothing in the title or question states that `float` values or objects are shifted. The phrase “shifting with floats” may simply refer to a situation that involves shifting and involves floats. I have gone rowing with friends, but I did not row my friends.

Comment: Are you in the same class with [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190303/how-does-the-bit-layout-of-the-floats-give-me-certain-values-after-bit-shifting)?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the float values of a, b, and c after running this code?

When `int` is 32-bits, the below integer shifts are well defined and exact.  Code is not shifting a `float` [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67196250/shifting-with-floats/67208880#comment118775467_67196250).

```
// OK with 32-bit int
1 << 25
1 << 26
1 << 27
```

Casts to `float`, the above power-of-2 values, are also well defined with no precision loss.

```
// OK and exact
(float) (1 << 25)
(float) (1 << 26)
(float) (1 << 27)
```

Adding to those to a `double` 1.0 are well defined exact sums.  A typical `double` has a 53 bit significand and can represent `0x8000001.0p0` exactly.   e.g.: `DBL_MANT_DIG == 53`

```
// Let us use hexadecimal FP notation
1.0 + ((float) (1 << 25))  // 0x2000001.0p0 or 0x1.0000008p+25
1.0 + ((float) (1 << 26))  // 0x4000001.0p0 or 0x1.0000004p+26
1.0 + ((float) (1 << 27))  // 0x8000001.0p0 or 0x1.0000002p+27
```

Finally code attempts to assign `double` values to a `float`, while within the range of a typical `float` encoding, cannot represent the values exactly.

A [typical `float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has a 24 bit significand.  e.g.: `FLT_MANT_DIG == 24`

> If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. C17dr § 6.3.1.4 2.

A typical implementation-defined manner rounds to nearest, ties to even.

```
  float s = 0x0800001.0p0; printf("%a\n", s);
  float t = 0x1000001.0p0; printf("%a\n", t);// 0x1000001.0p0 1/2 way between two floats 
  float a = 0x2000001.0p0; printf("%a\n", a);
  float b = 0x4000001.0p0; printf("%a\n", b);
  float c = 0x8000001.0p0; printf("%a\n", c);
```

Output

```
0x1.000002p+23   // exact conversion double to float
0x1p+24          
0x1p+25
0x1p+26
0x1p+27
```

---

> Explain why the bit layout of a, b, and c causes each value to be what it is.

The bit layout is not the issue.  It is the property of the `float` with  `FLT_MANT_DIG == 24`, a 24-bit significand and *implementation defined behavior*, that results in the rounding of the `double` value to the nearby `float` one.  Any `float` layout with `FLT_MANT_DIG == 24` would have like results.